# Sql query to get all metadata for a post

Tags: database, sql

I have three tables in my database one is users table the other is posts and `wp_post` meta. In the user table I have all the user details . In the wp_posts table I have different posts types .

I want to select the post_type as "projects" . and want to show all the details of the post like the post id, `post_author`(it is basically the user-id who posted the project ). Then again each project there are different descriptions like the project level, duration, price etc which all are coming from the post_meta . But with my query I can see a lot of meta against my single project and it has shown me a big data .

I have used three joins to show the data . Please if anyone can help me in getting the exact meta values against each project . The code I have attached below . Also going to add the database structure for reference .

```
SELECT wp_users.*,wp_posts.*,wp_postmeta.*
FROM wp_users
LEFT JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_users.ID=wp_posts.post_author
LEFT join wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.ID=wp_postmeta.post_id
```

Comment: In wordpress you have a function to get metadata, get_post_meta. Maybe this can help you get all the metadata that you need without a sql query

Comment: Your query is basically a very convoluted way of asking for all the rows in the user post and post meta tables, why are you trying to use raw SQL? What are you trying to achieve that requires this?

Comment: Basically i want to fetch this data and then insert it into the simple laravel database .